# why my onauthenticate event handler being called twice sometimes?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am using asp:login control to verify user name and password. Following is the control. To track login attempts, I use a session variable LoginCount. We only allow three tries. Also, we use WebControlAdapter to customerize the asp:login control. But somehow, sometimes, the event handler Login1_Authenticat gets called twice, which increase the LoginCount by 2, for just one try. Can anybody help me figure out where went wrong?

```
<asp:Login 
      ID="Login1" 
      runat="server" 
      OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
      DestinationPageUrl="index.aspx" TitleText="" DisplayRememberMe="false" UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Username is required." PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Password is required."
    />

   public class LoginAdapter : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters.WebControlAdapter
    {
        private enum State
        {
            LoggingIn,
            Failed,
            Success,
        }
        State _state = State.LoggingIn;

        ...    
        public LoginAdapter()
        {
            _state = State.LoggingIn;
        }

        /// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// PROTECTED        

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            Login login = Control as Login;
            if (Extender.AdapterEnabled && (login != null))
            {
                RegisterScripts();
                login.LoggedIn += OnLoggedIn;
                login.LoginError += OnLoginError;
                _state = State.LoggingIn;
            }
        }
...
```

update: It turned out to be a bug in LoginAdapter. I tired the fix offered in following link, it works. https://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/workitem/234

Comment: User session is identified by cookie, so as long as user don't persist session cookie, he can attempt to log-in as many times as he wants, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your users are clicking twice on the Login button? What about using some js code to disable the button in client side before posting to the server? Add a javascript function to the OnClientClick to disable the button and avoiding this.

Comment: No. I have the problem when I was debugging it. If I disable the webcontroladapter, the problem went away. I suspect something is wrong in my webcontroladapter part, but don't know where.